# Microsoft Graph Toolkit no have result match for some of the Azure AD users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Recently found some weird case when trying to use mgt people picker to search my tenancy Azure AD user with below tag.

```
<mgt-people-picker type="any" transitive-search="true"></mgt-people-picker>
```

Following is summary of info used:

a) Single tenant, does not allowed personal Microsoft account.

b) All API permission requires are granted in application and in app registration.

```
            "User.Read",
            "User.ReadBasic.All",
            "People.Read",
            "People.Read.All",
            "Contacts.Read",
            "Directory.Read.All",
            "User.Read.All",
            "Member.Read.Hidden",
            "Domain.Read.All",
            "User.ReadWrite.All",
            "APIConnectors.Read.All"
```

c) admin consent is given.
d) I'm using api/proxy to connect.

Somehow, I only can found some of the users, some of the users was not found. From mgt people picker UI, i just enter three to four character or full email address to search it but the return result is not correct. And i found that when it return incorrect result it have error on retrieving photo values. Sample error as below

[image]

I have tried to use [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to test it. Apparently, it is also cannot return the correct result match. But only using following query test, it is able to return the correct user to me. but when using mgt people picker, it cannot. Any advise are much appreciated. I'm just guessing it is something related to Azure AD user profile settings or it is something related to my application configuration or something else. Hope can some clues for me to resolve this issue. For your information, I have all admin rights to access all resources in my organization Azure environment. If there is information that I have missing, please do let me know, I will edit the post to include it.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<email address>
```

Test result by using Graph Explorer as reference, which only return partial only (majority not return):
[image]

Comment: When you say "I have tried to use Graph Explorer to test it. Apparently, it is also cannot return the correct result match.", how do you test it? Calling which endpoint in Graph explorer?

Comment: use this query url "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people?$search=shu" in Graph Explorer stated in my post to see the response preview under Graph Explorer. Which does not show related user profile (basic) returned. I have edit post to have included image what I have did with Graph Explorer

Comment: I use your `<mgt-people-picker type="any" transitive-search="true"></mgt-people-picker>` to test from my side and find the actual call is `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people?$search="shu"&$top=6&$filter=personType/class eq 'Person'`. It has `$top=6` which means only returning the first 6 items. And it also has a filter `$filter=personType/class eq 'Person'`. So please use this call to test in Microsoft Graph explorer to see if the results are consistent.

Comment: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$search="displayName:ang"&$filter=startsWith(displayname,'ang')&$orderBy=displayName&$select=id,displayName,mail` when i try to use above query url/endpoint to do searching it will show correct result. Question here: how do i ensure mgt-people-picker trigger correct endpoint to my api/proxy?

Comment: Besides, you said `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people?$search=shu` doesn't return enough results to you. I think it may be because you didn't understand the API correctly. This API retrieves a collection of person objects ordered by their relevance to the user, which is determined by the user's communication and collaboration patterns, and business relationships. See details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-people?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: No. I think mgt-people-picker calls `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people?$search="{search_value}"&$top=6&$filter=personType/class eq 'Person'` is by design.

Comment: Hi Allen, the result is consistent between Microsoft Graph explorer and with my application result. Actually, person name which start with "shu" or contains "shu" is less than 6 persons, so it should be able to show all the relevant results. I'm just thinking is there a way that I can configure <mgt-people-picker to force using users filter instead of people search?

Comment: Do you have any suggestion? Because I'm using this people picker to do configuration for approval matrix. So searching my relevance people may not look relevant to me. Do you think I should interrupting the query url in the middle before executing the url in my api/proxy class?

Comment: In fact, since you specify `type="any"`, it will call three endpoints: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people?$search="ttt"&$top=6&$filter=personType/class eq 'Person'`, `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$search="displayName:ttt" OR "mail:ttt"&$top=6`, `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=(startswith(displayName,'ttt') or startswith(mailNickname,'ttt') or startswith(mail,'ttt'))&$top=6`.  You can specify `type="person"`, which will exclude the group endpoint.

Comment: Related doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/people-picker#properties. See `type`. Please let me know if there is anything unclear.

Comment: i tried to specify type="person", the result is not correct. for demo/testing purpose, i change the type to "any", I hope able to see those results returned. However, still no luck. However, I have just tested by changing the type="person" and show-max=50, however, still does not return that user into the result. Even I have enter full display name correctly.  But by using this `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$search="displayName:ang"&$filter=startsWith(displayname,'ang')&$orderBy=displayName&$select=id,displayName,mail` I was able to get the desired result.

Comment: I'm afraid that calling `/me/people` in mgt-people-picker is defined in the official JS package, so we cannot change it. You should customize a picker to call `/users?$count=true&$search="displayName:ang"&$filter=startsWith(displayname,'ang')&$orderBy=displayName&$select=id,displayName,mail` for it.

Comment: Thanks Allen for the advise. I will following Microsoft Graph API development to see the improvement over the time.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this issue that /me/people endpoint does not able to show relevant search result. I have did following code changes in my api/proxy to intercepting the process before sending the request to MS Graph as below. This maybe is a workaround to make it works. In future, if there is better option, I will make a change on it.
Hope this can help someone who faced the same issue as I'm.

```
var url = $"{GetBaseUrlWithoutVersion(_graphClient)}/{all}{qs.ToUriComponent()}";

            if(url.StartsWith("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people?$search="))
            {
                string url2 = @"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$filter=startsWith(displayname,%27{0}%27) or startsWith(userPrincipalName,%27{1}%27)";

                Uri searchUri = new Uri(url);
                string paramSearch = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(searchUri.Query).Get("$search").Replace('"', ' ').Trim();

//we do not want to search for any email address, just for custom search only
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paramSearch) && !paramSearch.Contains("@xxx"))
                {
                    url = string.Format(url2, paramSearch, paramSearch);
                }                
            }
```